# "Starting flush of map output" takes very long time in hadoop map task

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, flush

I execute a map task on a small file (3-4 MB), but map output is relatively large (150 MB). After showing Map 100%, it takes long time to finish the spill. Please suggest how can I reduce this period. Following are some sample logs...

```
13/07/10 17:45:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/07/10 17:45:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 98% reduce 0%
13/07/10 17:45:34 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:45:35 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/07/10 17:45:37 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:45:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:45:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:45:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:45:49 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:45:52 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:45:55 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:45:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:01 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:04 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:07 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:10 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:13 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:16 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:19 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:22 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:25 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:28 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:31 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:34 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:37 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:49 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:52 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:55 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:46:58 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:01 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:04 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:07 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:10 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:13 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:16 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:19 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:22 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:25 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:28 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:31 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:34 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:37 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:40 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:43 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:45 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
13/07/10 17:47:45 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local_0003_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
13/07/10 17:47:45 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/07/10 17:47:45 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local_0003_m_000000_0' done.
...............................
...............................
...............................
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 22
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Output Format Counters 
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Written=13401245
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=18871098
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_READ=7346566
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=35878426
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS_BYTES_WRITTEN=18621307
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Input Format Counters 
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Bytes Read=2558288
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=740000
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output materialized bytes=13320006
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=740000
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=71040
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=740000
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=1480000
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=119998400
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=0
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=1178009600
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=7499900
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=7499900
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=122
13/07/10 17:47:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=740000
```

**Map Task Source code:**

```
public class GsMR2MapThree extends Mapper<Text, Text, LongWritable,DoubleWritable>{

    private DoubleWritable distGexpr = new DoubleWritable();
    private LongWritable m2keyOut = new LongWritable();
    int trMax,tstMax;

    protected void setup(Context context) throws java.io.IOException, java.lang.InterruptedException {

        Configuration conf =context.getConfiguration();
        tstMax = conf.getInt("mtst", 10);
        trMax = conf.getInt("mtr", 10);

    }

    public void map(Text key, Text values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = values.toString();

        double Tij=0.0,TRij=0.0, dist=0;
        int i=0,j;
        long m2key=0;
        String[] SLl = new String[]{};

        Configuration conf =context.getConfiguration();

        m2key = Long.parseLong(key.toString());
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        j=0;
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

            String test = tokenizer.nextToken();
            if(j==0){
                Tij = Double.parseDouble(test);
            }
            else if(j==1){
                TRij = Double.parseDouble(test);
            }
            else if(j==2){
                SLl = StringUtils.split(conf.get(test),",");
            }
            j++;
        }
        //Map input ends

        //Distance Measure function
        dist = (long)Math.pow( (Tij - TRij), 2);

        //remove gid from key 
        m2key = m2key / 100000;
        //Map2 <key,value> emit starts
        for(i=0; i<SLl.length;i++){
               long m2keyNew = (Integer.parseInt(SLl[i])*(trMax*tstMax))+m2key;
            m2keyOut.set(m2keyNew);
            distGexpr.set(dist);
            context.write(m2keyOut,distGexpr);
        }
        //<key,value> emit done
    }

}
```

**Sample Map Input:** The last variable in each line get an integer array from broadcast variables. Each line will produce around 100-200 output records.

```
10100014    1356.3238 1181.63 gs-4-56
10100026    3263.1167 3192.4131 gs-3-21
10100043    1852.0 1926.3962 gs-4-76
10100062    1175.5925 983.47125 gs-3-19
10100066    606.59125 976.26625 gs-8-23
```

**Sample Map Output:**

```
10101   8633.0
10102   1822.0
10103   13832.0
10104   2726470.0
10105   1172991.0
10107   239367.0
10109   5410384.0
10111   7698352.0
10112   6.417
```

Comment: Can you post your mapper code (or at least a description of what your mapper functionally does), sample input record and output record(s)? Do you have a cleanup method ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added source code for this map task and sample input & output. I didn't use any cleanup method. Actually there was many spills earlier. So, I changed io.sort.record.percent and few other settings. Then spills are minimized but overall execution time remained same.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have solved that (2 years after posting the original message), but just for anyone who steps into the same problem, I will try providing some suggestions.

Judging from your counters, I understand that you already use compression (since the number of map output materialized bytes is different to the number of map output bytes), which is a good thing. You can further compress the output of the mapper, by using the variable-length encoded [VLongWritable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/VLongWritable.html) class, as the map output key type. (There used to be a VDoubleWritable class, too, if I am not mistaken, but it must have been deprecated by now).

In the for loop, in which you emit the output, there is no need to set the `distGexpr` variable each time. It is always the same, so set it just before the for loop. You can also store a long with the product of `trMax*tstMax` outside the loop and not calculate it on each iteration.

If possible, make your input key LongWritable (from the previous job), so that you can save the `Long.parseLong()` and the `Text.toString()` invocations.

If possible (depending on your reducer), use a combiner, to reduce the size of spilled bytes.

I could not find a way to skip that `Integer.parseInt()` call within the for loop, but it would save some time if you could initially load `SLl` as `int[]`.